# Why does Pinia state mutate when using getters?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I would expect that when calling a `getter` from the store and assigning it to a variable, any changes to that variable would **not** result in the store state being updated, as I'm not calling the state directly.

This is true for primitive data, but not for object references.

```js
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'

    import { useStudyStore } from '@/study/studyStore'
    const StudyStore = useStudyStore()

    let string = ref(StudyStore.getString)
    string.value = 'bar2' // Does NOT update store

    let object = ref(StudyStore.getObject)
    object.value.a = 2 // DOES update store

    const simpleArray = ref(StudyStore.getSimpleArray)
    simpleArray.value[0] = 5 // DOES update store

</script>

// Store
export const useStudyStore = defineStore('study', {
    state: () => ({
        string: 'bar',
        object: { a: 1 },
        simpleArray: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    }),
    getters: {
        getString(state) {
            return state.string
        },
        getObject(state) {
            return state.object
        },
        getSimpleArray(state) {
            return state.simpleArray
        },
       
    },
})
```

I understand that this is due to how referencing works in Javascript, but I expected Pinia to handle this in some way to prevent accidental updating of the store. Is it really the case that any time we want to protect a non-primitive state value in the store from being mutated we need to parse/stringify them?

```js
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(StudyStore.getSimpleArray))
```

Comment: There's no way how `ref(StudyStore.getString)` could result in a store being updated. `StudyStore.getString === 'bar'`. It's the same as writing `ref('bar')`. This is specific to how JS works at this point. How can it guess that you meant to update store key that holds 'bar' value?

Comment: Hi Estus. My comment in the code refers to how `StudyStore.getString` **doesn't** update the store, which is what I expect. My question is specifically referring to why the store state is being updated for non-primitive types. I know it's because they're object references, I'm just confused as to how this happens with Pinia when I'm calling a getter (ie, a computed property).

Comment: "I expected Pinia to handle this in some way to prevent accidental updating of the store." - not sure why this was expected, but it shouldn't. StudyStore.getSimpleArray === StudyStore.simpleArray. It's acceptable and sometimes desirable to mutate a state returned by a getter, although mutating a state outside actions is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the `simpleArray` being **deeply reactive**

Generally, you'd expect that everything in store is deeply reactive

If you want to explicitly remove reactivity, use

```
// the object will be non-reactive, you'll have to `store.simpleArray = store.simpleArray` to update it
simpleArray: markRaw([1, 2, 3, 4])

// the returned value would be non-reactive, but would stealthy change reactive object
getSimpleArray() {
   return toRaw(this.simpleArray)
}

// will disallow changes on TS level
getSimpleArray() {
   return this.simpleArray as DeepReadonly<typeof this.this.simpleArray>
}

// will disallow changes on proxy level
getSimpleArray() {
   return deepReadonly(this.simpleArray)
}
```

(readonlys may be not is @vue but in @vueuse/core or whatever)

---

why deeply reactive, say you have deep options

```
options: Record<someId, { colorOfSomeId: string }>
```

obviously expected to be deep reactive